# Check the render method of `ExpoRootComponent`

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to use react-native navigation. I installed the app, everything went alright. Now I'm having this problem with Expo when I try and create a navigation in both ios and web:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

> Check the render method of `ExpoRoot`.

registerRootComponent

```
  11 |   AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => withExpoRoot(component));
  12 |   if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
  13 |     const rootTag = document.getElementById('root') ?? document.getElementById('main');
> 14 |     AppRegistry.runApplication('main', { rootTag });
  15 |   }
  16 | }
  17 |
```

**Heres my App.js**

```
import { Routes } from './src/Routes';

export default Routes;
```

**Routes**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();



function Home() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Some text!</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
function Routes() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={Home}/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}

export default Routes;
```

[I'm just following a tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hln37dE19bs)

The app still runs if I use this as my App.js:

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import socket from './socektConfig';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
import { Routes } from './src/Routes';
```

to

```
import Routes from './src/Routes';
```

You have done a default export so you should import like this

Also in App.js do this

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Routes/>
  );
}
```